# JQuery shake changes position

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a login form shake with the shake effect from jquery ui and this is the problem: the form moves down to the bottom of the screen, shakes and then restores it's original position

code to make it shake:

```
function onLoginFailed() {
$(".nblogin").effect("shake");
}
```

css for nblogin:

```
.nblogin {
top:50%;
left:50%;
background-color:rgba(102,153,153,0.7);
color:white;
position:absolute;
margin-left:-15%; /* half of width */
margin-top:-10%;  /* half of height */
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 20px;

}
```

html for nblogin:

```
<div class="nblogin" style="display:none">
<h1>Log-in</h1><br>
<input id="nbUser" runat="server" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
<input id="nbPass" runat="server" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
<input id="nbSubmit" runat="server" type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" onserverclick="nbSubmit_Click" onmouseover="nbHover(this.id);" onmouseout="nbNoHover(this.id);" value="login">
</div>
```

Expected behaviour:

The form changes it's x position (shaking) and keeps it's y position

what I get:

The form moves down about 5%, shakes, and moves back to it's original position

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the jQuery UI shake effect overrides your margin value with '0' so that causes the form to move down.

Try changing you CSS so that it does not use the negative margins.
If you are trying to center the form on the screen try this instead:

```
.nblogin {
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    background-color:rgba(102,153,153,0.7);
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```